# Error 42000 Must Declare the scalar variable "@ID"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, ado

Error while setting parameter in the sql query

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(cs);


OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select CustomerID, LastName, FirstName from Customers.Customer.Customer_Details where CustomerID = @ID", con);
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text));
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Earlier answers just told to add value for the parameter, but I don't think that is something in my question.

Comment: it's clear in the answer you need to use `?` and then add parameters. In your case it should be `OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select CustomerID, LastName, FirstName from Customers.Customer.Customer_Details where CustomerID = ?", con);` rest will be as it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot shekhar it worked.